# Export Ubuntu with all pre-installed applications to different host system

Tags: networking, server

Since my server provider can't help me accessing internet network directly from the rented server, I need to set up Ubuntu on my local PC and export it.

The plan is:

1. Create new VM Ubuntu on local PC using Hyper V/ VirtualBox
2. Instal Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTD
3. Download and install all programs needed later on (Google Cloud SDK Shell, Docker for Ubuntu, python, 2 ML models images from VertexAI, set local ports for them etc).
4. Export system to the server. Host is running on Windows Server 2022.
5. Start using Ubuntu with all previously added programs

Should it be working or there might be discrepancies between origin host system Win10 and target host system WS 2022?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Apologies, but I’m slightly confused by some of the statements and expectations. Are you saying that the completed server will be running *without* access to the Internet? Will it be airgapped or simply limited to a LAN? Given the software you would like to install, I cannot see this system being wholly independent 

Comment: Generally, a properly-running VM Guest should produce similar results on any Host for most users. Discrepancies between two Windows VM Hosts and whatever Host virtualization applications seems off-topic here.

Comment: If the host is "Windows Server 2022", I assume will be running your VM inside HyperV. Between your choice of "Hyper V/ VirtualBox", I would naturally choose HyperV to match the destination. If you use VirtualBox, you might accidentally depend on features like its guest extensions

Comment: @matigo it was confusing, my apologies. Rented server has a full access to the internet, but setting up an Ubuntu VM under Hyper V can't access network connection no matter what I do. Spent about 16 hours trying to troubleshoot it, and still nothing. Hence the idea to set up Ubuntu with all needed applications on my PC and export it to the server, where Ubuntu won't need internet anymore as it will communicate with hosted programms through local ports only.